# Win10 OpenSssh: ssh-add gives err "invalid format" for key file

Tags: windows-10, openssh

On windows 10, the ssh-add commant is giving the following error:
`Could not add identity "C:\users\<username>\.ssh\id_rsa_win": invalid format`

I generated the key like this: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -N 'my pass phrase' -C 'generated by windows openssh' -f C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\id_rsa_win`

```
Get-Command ssh-keygen

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ssh-add.exe                                        7.7.2.1    C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-add.exe
```

```
Get-Command ssh-add

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ssh-add.exe                                        7.7.2.1    C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-add.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-add` from an elevated prompt? Please try that. Just type `Powershell` on the Start Menu, right click on top of it and `Run as Administrator`.
Try generating a key from there and adding it again. That can be the issue.

Some commands to test as well:

```
    ssh-add -l #list existing identities
    ssh-add -D # delete existing identities (run only if you can)
```

Other than that, found [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1454) thread where the user magically solved the issue  and was unsure if it was whether a restart or an update that solved it. So worst case scenario, maybe try updating your OpenSSH version. You can find the latest versions [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)